# mediaPlayer global on another activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

I want to play music in another activity using one mediaplayer. Example
MediaPlayer main activity and a description of what to play i.e url on another activity me how to pass values from one activity to the mediaplayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Service:

```
public class BackgroundSound extends Service {
private static final String TAG = null;
MediaPlayer player;

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.audiofile);
    player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
    player.setVolume(100, 100);

}

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    player.start();
    return 1;
}

public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    // TO DO
}

public IBinder onUnBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TO DO Auto-generated method
    return null;
}

public void onStop() {

}

public void onPause() {

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() {

}
  }
```

Then in your another Activity:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityb);

    Intent svc = new Intent(this, BackgroundSound.class);
    startService(svc);

    msg.show();

}

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but could you throw the archive with the program) I don't even master lemaster)

Comment: Well i dont have the program, but i can tell you that you can just copy this and paste from public class declarations up to bottom. if you want to add anything, only make sure are you in onCreate or out of it. else tell me your error in case, i try to help you.